# Evaluating an expression using stack in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a Python code that will evaluate an expression using stack. I have the following code, where `numStk` is a stack that holds number and `optStk` that holds operators. In the expression `2+3*4-6`, at the end of `for` loop, `numStack` contains `2`, `12`, and `6`; and `optStk` contains `-` and `+`. Now how can I make my `setOps()` function to pop elements from the two stacks to do the evaluate the expression?

```
def main():
      raw_expression = input("Enter an expression: ")
      expression = raw_expression.replace(" ", "")
      for i in expression:
          if (i in numbers):
              numStk.push(i)
          else:
              setOps(i)
              optStk.push(i)
      ## code needed to evaluate the rest of the elements in stackstack
      return valStk.top()
```

My `setOps(i)` function is as follow:

```
def repeatOps(refOp):
      while (len(valStk) > 1 and operators.index(refOp) <= operators.index(optStk.top())):
      x = numStk.pop()
      y = numStk.pop()
      op = optStk.pop()
      numStk.push(str(eval(x+op+y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if I fill in all the stuff you left out, there are issues with your code: `setOps()` appears to be called `repeatOps()`; `numStk` is sometimes called `valStk`; you evaluate in the wrong order, e.g. "6-5" is evaluated "5-6"; you're calling `eval()`!

Below's my filling out and reworking of your code to address the above issues:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

DIGITS = "0123456789"

# position implies (PEMDAS) priority, low to high
OPERATORS = OrderedDict([  \
    ['+', lambda a, b: a + b], \
    ['-', lambda a, b: a - b], \
    ['*', lambda a, b: a * b], \
    ['/', lambda a, b: a / b], \
    ])

def operator_priority(character):
    return list(OPERATORS.keys()).index(character)

class Stack(list):
    """ minimalist stack implementation """

    def push(self, thing):
        self.append(thing)

    def top(self):
        return self[-1]

def evaluate(expression):
    numStk = Stack()
    optStk = Stack()

    def setOps(refOp):
        while numStk and optStk and operator_priority(refOp) <= operator_priority(optStk.top()):
            y = numStk.pop()
            x = numStk.pop()
            op = optStk.pop()
            print(x, op, y)  # debugging
            numStk.push(OPERATORS[op](x, y))

    for i in expression:
        if i in DIGITS:
            numStk.push(int(i))
        else:
            setOps(i)
            optStk.push(i)

    if optStk:
        # evaluate the rest of the elements in stacks
        setOps(list(OPERATORS.keys())[0])  # trigger using lowest priority operator

    return numStk.top()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_expression = input("Enter an expression: ")
    expression = raw_expression.replace(" ", "")
    print(evaluate(expression))
```

Far from perfect but something to get you going:

**EXAMPLE**

```
> python3 test.py
Enter an expression: 2+3*4-6
3 * 4
12 - 6
2 + 6
8
>
```

To address your original question, the key to finishing the evaluation seems to be running `setOps()` with a fictitious, low priority operator if there's anything left in the `optStk`.